# Odoo Show mobile on customer search

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

Using Odoo 10 - When creating a Sales Order or Invoice. When you search a customer it only shows the customer name. The problem is if you have two customers who's name is John Smith how do you know which one to select. If it could show mobile number also this would solve that problem.

[image]

Not sure where to edit code to show mobile number

Answer (score 2):

You can modify override name_get function to get this result.

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('name', 'phone')
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for customer in self:
        name = customer.name + ' ' + customer.phone
        result.append((customer.id, name))
    return result
```

Comment: I tried above but did not work. I get no errors just does not show customer.phone

Comment: There  are are 2 functions involved in this kind or search first one is name_get and 2nd one is name_search. You can find name_search syntax in addons folder it as been written for multiple models. override both functions and debug what is the exact problem. The solution I have given is a working on in various use cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your custom field(Char). Where you can concrete customer name and mobile no. After that you make this custom field rec_name by name_get method. This will help you.